# filter from array with multiple value js

Tags: javascript, object

I need to filter array with compare string and numeric result values. But get filter array values, while I enter both values. Otherwise I can't get values. That means if enter only string value I can't get filter array values.

```
var fullArray = [{stringValue:"apple", numericValue:"40"}, {stringValue:"banana", numericValue:"20"}, {stringValue:"berry", numericValue:"30"}, {stringValue:"mango", numericValue:"10"}]

    _.filter(fullArray, function(el){
        if(el.stringValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(stringResultValue.toLowerCase())>=0 && el.numericValue==numericResultValue){
            resultFilter.push(el);
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is `resultFilter`, `stringResultValue`, `numericResultValue`? Take an example of input data and expected result please

Comment: See [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Lodash's `filter` should work similar.

Comment: @AndrewParamoshkin, resultFilter is get a final result array. stringResultValue and numericResultValue both are already get value from click function.

Comment: @barbsan, yeah there is example is only filter string or numeric. I need filter with both values.

Comment: @vijayaganth just use proper condition in your callback with `&&` (for both equal) or `||` (if only one property equal is enough) operator

Comment: @barbsan, yeah thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

`filter` expects a function that returns something truthy for elements that should be in the new array, and something falsey if they shouldn't. You should have something like:

```
var fullArray = [{stringValue:"apple", numericValue:"40"}, {stringValue:"banana", numericValue:"20"}, {stringValue:"berry", numericValue:"30"}, {stringValue:"mango", numericValue:"10"}]

resultFilter = _.filter(fullArray, function(el){
    return el.stringValue.toLowerCase().indexOf(stringResultValue.toLowerCase()) >= 0 && 
           el.numericValue === numericResultValue;
});
```

A shorter version, using ES6 syntax:

```
resultFilter = fullArray.filter(el => 
    el.stringValue.toLowerCase().includes(stringResultValue.toLowerCase()) && 
    el.numericValue === numericResultValue;
);
```